# Symfony/propel form saving an object with additional properties

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, symfony-forms

First, let me say, that I find the sfFormPropel form's interface inconsistent.
There is `bind()`, which returns nothing, but triggers validation, `save()` which returns the saved object, and `bindAndSave()`, which returns boolean, actually the return value of `isValid()`. Now, I have a working application, but I don't feel the code is right, and I'm quite new to `symfony`, so perhaps I'm missing something.

The object I need to create needs some external properties, that are not presented in the form, are external to the model, and are handled by the application (for example, the userId of the user, that created the entity, an external-generated guid, etc.).

Right now the flow is as follows:

- get values from request and bind them to form
- check if form is valid
- if it's valid, add additional values and bind them to form one more time
- save the form and return the object

The obvious answer would to add application-specific values to the values, retrieved from request, but *It does not make sense to bind the application-specific values if the form is not valid,  since they can be potentially expensive operations, may create database records, etc.* Additionally, it should not be possible to pass those values with the post request, they should come from application only.

Now, I though that I have to let the model do these things, but since the data is external to the model, action still need to pass it to the model. The problem is, if I call `$form->getObject()` after `bind()`, it still has the old data, and not the data submitted.

What is the correct way to implement this kind of post-processing?

*Second bounty is started to award the other valuable answer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends of who has "knowledge" about the extra attributes. If they're really request specific, thus need to be processed in the controller, I go for binding, testing if valid and then update the bound object. To get the updated object with the bound (and validated) fields use the `updateObject` function.

```
$form->bind(..)
if ($form->isValid()) {

   $obj = $form->updateObject(); // Updates the values of the object with the cleaned up values. (returns object)
   $obj->foo = 'bar';

   $obj->save();
}
```

But since this normally is also behaviour that is form specific, I usually go for overriding the Form class. By overriding the `doUpdateValues()` function you can easily access submitted data, and append your own data. Of course you can also go higher in the chain, and override the `save()` function.
To set custom data for this form, you can also 'publish' public methods, which can then be used by the controller.

Comment: The controllers has the knowledge - one of the values is the current user id (which can be easily set to the form) , another is an ID generated and retrieved with a call to another model (and I don't want to perform that call is the submitted form is not valid), and it's possible for other values, retrieved by other models to be added in the future. The question is actually how to update the bound object without triggering validation on the already processed fields?

Comment: Have you tried calling `doUpdateObject()` to get the 'bound' object? (see my updated answer)

Comment: it works and the code is much cleaner now. Thank you. processValues() will be useful for me for other situations. I'll leave the question and bounty open until Friday, other suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be setting your default values on the object you are passing to the form constructor. For example if you want to set the logged in user id on an object you are creating:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->setUserId($this->getUser()->getId());
$form = new ArticleForm($article);
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
  $form->bind($request->getParameter('article'));
  if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->save();
  }
}
```

Likewise for existing object, you can load the record and change any properties before passing it to the form constructor.

EDIT:

If you want to modify the object after validating, you can use $form->updateObject() like Grad suggests in his response. If the generated values depend on the submitted values, you can override sfFormObject::processValues():

```
class UserForm {

  public function processValues($values) {
    $values['hash'] = sha1($values['id'] . $values['username']);
    return parent::processValues($values);
  }

}
```

In case you need something from the action, you can always pass it as an option to the form:

```
$form = new UserForm($user, array('foo' => $bar));
```

That way, you can use $this->getOption('foo') anywhere in your form code, eg. in processValues().

Comment: Thank you for joining the discussion. This still would require to generate the GUID before saving the object, and that object may be never saved. What if the value depends on the submitted data in the form, for example you enter tags, and hash is generated based on all the entered words (just example). Maybe in some way the model have to be altered to allow this to happen. What the ubdateObject() does in PropelForm? Maybe doSave() of the form have to be overwritten?